# select value in data table by other coloumn

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` `test`

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    measure = c("l1", "l2", "l3", "r1", "r2", "r3", "l1", "l2", 
    "l3", "l4", "r1", "r2", "r3"), side = c("l", "l", "l", "r", 
    "r", "r", "l", "l", "l", "l", "r", "r", "r"), Decide_val = c(120, 
    122, 125, 135, 133, 124, 150, 148, 144, 146, 140, 138, 133
    ), Col_1 = 1:13, Col_2 = 13:1), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")) -> test
```

I want to select the last two values based on `id` and `side` then average these like so

```
test.two <- test[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(tail(x,2))),.SDcols = 4:6,by = list(id,side)]

test.two
   id side Decide_val Col_1 Col_2
1:  1    l      123.5   2.5  11.5
2:  1    r      128.5   5.5   8.5
3:  2    l      145.0   9.5   4.5
4:  2    r      135.5  12.5   1.5
```

Finally I want to by `id` keep the value that is highest in `Decide_Val` and do this for `Col_1` and `Col_2` based on `Decide_val`
***Output would be :***

```
   id side Decide_val Col_1 Col_2
2:  1    r      128.5   5.5   8.5
3:  2    l      145.0   9.5   4.5
```

Comment: `test.two[test.two[, .I[which.max(Decide_val)], id]$V1]`

Comment: @Ronak Shah follow up question, is there way to check if l and r are equal by id in decide val then do a which.max on a different col if they are?